# Autocomplete organization

Tags: contribution-page, organization

Is there any extension that converts on-behalf Organization name field to a drop down on online contribution pages? Seems like [publicautocomplete](https://github.com/TechToThePeople/publicautocomplete) works only for current_employer field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an extension for this and can be found at https://civicrm.org/extensions/autocomplete-organization